# Why do i keep getting undefined when I search for elements of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, javascript-objects

I've an asp.net core with react project, I have this code here inside my react component:

```js
const staticTxt = stattxt.filter(x => x.id === userIdD && x.taskId === item.id)[0];
```

I did a console log for each variable in this line and I get this for stattxt:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "taskId": 3,
        "value": "some content"
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "taskId": 5,
        "value": "some content"
    }
]
```

and this for useridD and item.id:

```json
userIdD: 1002
item.id: 5
```

why does staticTxt keeps returning undefined? I've also tried .find but it returns the same result.

Comment: Are you sure of the types of `userIdD` and `item.id`? You are using `===` the strict, non-type-coercing equality operator. When I try your example it works for me, but if either of those variables held a string instead of a number, you would get undefined.

Comment: yeah it gives undefined if, for example `userIdD = "1002";` instead of a numeric value

Comment: I think you have type problem, try converting `userIdD` to number first.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I feel a sense of regret about the prolonged existence of this issue.

Comment: If you don't care about the types you can use `==`, the type-coercing equality operator.

Comment: Debug it: `const staticTxt = stattxt.filter(x => {  console.log(x.id, userIdD, x.id === userIdD, x.taskId, item.id, x.taskId === item.id);  return x.id === userIdD && x.taskId === item.id })[0]`

Comment: The `undefined` value is the result of an **empty filtered array** (no `stattxt` item met the filtering condition) where **accessing its first value** of cause does fail, hence the `undefined` value.

Answer (score -1):

Try == instead of ===. === is unnecessary in most cases.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

userIdD was a string, therefore returning an undefined

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).